# Lotus notes set logout automatically when processing excel vba sending lots of email out

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, vba

My computer and Lotus notes will be on together. I have the excel vba open the lotus notes for sending some emails out automatically.

However the lotus notes was set to be logout every half an hour and i need to login again with password which my program was frequently interrupted before the job finished. What can I do in this condition?

Comment: Dont let it log out then?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is dependent on being logged into Notes, I'm assuming you are using the Notes OLE classes. I.e., you've got VBA set up to use the "Lotus Notes Automation Classes": Notes.NotesSession, Notes.NotesDatabase, etc.

You should be using the "Lotus Notes Domino Objects", which are COM classes instead of OLE classes. Note the different prefix for these classes: Lotus.NotesSession, Lotus.NotesDatabase, etc.

The OLE classes actually drive the code in the running Notes client, so they require that it is running (they will start it if it's not), and logged in. The OLE classes go around the client and just use the instelled Notes DLLs, so the client does not have to be running and you don't have to be logged into it. Instead, your own code will have to authenticate. There are several ways that can happen, but usually it just means that when you run your VBA it will prompt you for your Notes password. It will authenticate only once, at the beginning of the run, regardless of the client's configured time-out.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Notes client software and set the user-session timeout value (or disable it).  Goto:

File, Security, User Security, then on the 'security basics' tab look for 'Automatically lock my notes ID after' X seconds. (a value of 0 may disable it?).

You need to use the same user-id used for VBA access.